# Is there a vscode snippet path variable that works in Windows and Linux?

Tags: linux, powershell, visual-studio-code, powershell-core

I want to write a pester test, that works both on Linux and on Windows. The test creates vscode snippets, and I want to be sure it creates them in the correct place.

I want to make my test as generic as possible, and test automatically at the right place according the OS.

I know on Windows I could use $env:AppDAta but that variable doesn't exists on linux. 
what could I use instead, which would work on both platforms.

Cheers!

Comment: Why not differentiate code with `$IsLinux/$IsWindows` automatic variables?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rely on *environment variables* across platforms, but .NET Core does make known / special folders available in a cross-platform manner via its [`[Environment]::GetFolderPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath) method.

Not all locations defined there in the abstract are available on all platforms, but `ApplicationData` is:

```
[Environment]::GetFolderPath('ApplicationData')
```

For username `jdoe`, the above yields the following paths:

- Windows: `C:\Users\jdoe\AppData\Roaming` (equivalent of: `$env:APPDATA`)
- Linux: `/home/jdoe/.config` (equivalent of: `$HOME/.config`)
- macOS: `/Users/jdoe/.config`  (equivalent of: `$HOME/.config`)

Also note [this proposal on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6966), which suggests exposing these folders in a more PowerShell-idiomatic way via a new namespace `$sf:` (for *s*pecial *f*older), so that `$sf:ApplicationData` would be the equivalent of the above command.

<sup>If you'd like to see that implemented, make your voice heard there. Even a simple "thumbs up" helps.</sup>

Comment: Question for my benefit. how would you ever get `[Environment]::GetFolderPath('ApplicationData')` to return anything related to Linux or macOS? I agree with all of the paths shown (thankfully most Linux apps now use `~/.config` instead of a smattering of `~/.whatever` individual config dirs). Just curious.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: You can install [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), which is based on the cross-platform [.NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx) framework, on macOS and/or Linux, and run the code there.